# Entity Framework Core join & include inner entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

```
 List<Item> Item = (from it in _context.Item
                    join iv in _context.ItemVersions on it.Id equals iv.ItemId
                    join iot in _context.ItemOriginalTitles on iv.Id equals iot.ItemVersionId                    
                    where term.ToLower() == "all" || (it.Name.ToLower() == term.ToLower() || it.Name.ToLower().Contains(term.ToLower()) || iot.Value.Contains(term) || 
                    queryable.Any(x => iot.Value.Contains(x.SearchText)))
                    select new Item
                    {
                        Id = it.Id,
                        Name = it.Name,
                        TypeCodeId = it.TypeCodeId,
                        TypeCode = it.TypeCode,
                        OriginalLangId = it.OriginalLangId,
                        SubGenreCodeId = it.SubGenreCodeId,
                        ItemVersions = it.ItemVersions
                    }
                ).Include("ItemVersions.OriginalTitles").ToList();
```

I am trying to add `OriginalTitles` to `ItemVersions` entity, as you can see, but not able to do that (`OriginalTitles` is always `null`). 
Item model:

```
public class Item
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int TypeCodeId { get; set; }
    public TypeCodes TypeCode { get; set; }
    public int? OriginalLangId { get; set; }
    public int SubGenreCodeId { get; set; }
    public List<ItemVersion> ItemVersions { get; set; }      
}
```

and my ItemVersions model:

```
 public class ItemVersion
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<ItemOriginalTitle> OriginalTitles { get; set; }
        public List<ItemShortTitle> ShortTitles { get; set; }
        public List<ItemSynopsis> ItemSynopsis { get; set; }
        public List<ItemLongSynopsis> ItemLongSynopsis { get; set; }
        public List<ItemLanguage> ItemLanguages { get; set; }
        public List<VersionChannel> VersionChannels { get; set; }
        public bool IsDefault { get; set; }
        public Item Item { get; set; }
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
    }
```

Looking for a way to include it at once, without the need to iterate over it, if it is possible. Thanks

Comment: If you have to use the string version of `Include` because the lambda version gives compiler errors you can be sure the Include doesn't have effect. It *may* work as `_context.Item.Include("ItemVersions.OriginalTitles")`, but I'm not sure because you didn't enter your EF version and the part on ignored Includes has been removed from the documentation, which probably indicates that the behavior isn't well defined/stable yet in EF core 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I initialized a new object, it doesn't matter that I included the inner entities. My solution was to return the db object and move the includes to it:

```
  Item = (from it in _context.Item.Include("ItemVersions.OriginalTitles")
                join iv in _context.ItemVersions on it.Id equals iv.ItemId
                join iot in _context.ItemOriginalTitles on iv.Id equals iot.ItemVersionId
                where term.ToLower() == "all" || (it.Name.ToLower() == term.ToLower() || it.Name.ToLower().Contains(term.ToLower()) || iot.Value.Contains(term) ||
                queryable.Any(x => iot.Value.Contains(x.SearchText)))
                select it          
       ).ToList();
```

Comment: What are you talking about @GertArnold? The reason I did this join is the search, the search is what matters

Comment: It is not working when initializing a new Item. What do you mean "they want"? I asked the question. why the down vote??

Answer (score 1):

Try (moved `Include` method to `join` clause, where the table is selected):

```
List<Item> Item = from it in _context.Item
                  join iv in _context.ItemVersions.Include("OriginalTitles") on it.Id equals iv.ItemId
                  join iot in _context.ItemOriginalTitles on iv.Id equals iot.ItemVersionId                    
                  where term.ToLower() == "all" || (it.Name.ToLower() == term.ToLower() || it.Name.ToLower().Contains(term.ToLower()) || iot.Value.Contains(term) || 
                  queryable.Any(x => iot.Value.Contains(x.SearchText)))
                  select new Item
                  {
                      Id = it.Id,
                      Name = it.Name,
                      TypeCodeId = it.TypeCodeId,
                      TypeCode = it.TypeCode,
                      OriginalLangId = it.OriginalLangId,
                      SubGenreCodeId = it.SubGenreCodeId,
                      ItemVersions = it.ItemVersions
                  };
```

Comment: @AaYy Try `.Include(iv => iv.OriginalTitles)`

Comment: I believe that the "select new Item" is not minding the includes

Comment: `Include(iv => iv.OriginalTitles)` is same thing. Not working..